# How to fetch current url parameter to pass in a href link

Tags: symfony, twig

Current Url :   **http://localhost/invite_project/web/app_dev.php/api/getall/5**

Redirection Url

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url(asset(''))}}app_dev.php/create/{ 'id': app.request.get('_route_params') }" class="btn btn-primary">Create>
```

I can't fetch `Id=5` in twig file using `app.request.get('_route_params')`

Comment: {{app.request.attributes.get('_route_params').id}}     I used this in url and it worked! ,
Hope it helps.

Comment: You should make that into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{app.request.attributes.get('_route_params').id}}     I used this in url and it worked!